# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is preseant on the requested resource

Tags: cors, multi-tenant, laravel-7

I'm using https://github.com/stancl/tenancy with subdomains. I've got this error when I'm getting data from subdomain and from my frontend (Angular).

I'm using https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors for the cors handling.

Here the include of laravel-cors in my app/Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

And my route in routes\Tenant.php

```
 Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd(\App\User::all());
        return response()->json('This is your multi-tenant application. The id of the current tenant is ' . tenant('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually with dd() function is not working.

If I change by

```
 Route::middleware([
    'web',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        //dd(\App\User::all());
        return response()->json(App\User::all());
    });
});
```

It's works